# Showing multiple images (in a frame) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm going to display multiple images in a specific format, i.e. a rectangular frame to show figures with same size and alongside with caption (below of each column), in Matlab. Something similar to the following figure. 
[image]

I found a [solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22387-imdisp) at Mathworks' file exchange but it could not produce the desired output.

Is there any specific function for doing so in Matlab?

Comment: What is undesired about the solution you found?

Comment: have a look at `subplot`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following program code can help you:

```
[X1,map1]=imread('forest.tif');
[X2,map2]=imread('trees.tif');
subplot(1,2,1), imshow(X1,map1)
subplot(1,2,2), imshow(X2,map2)
```